# Is it advisable to use cosmos input/output bindings for Azure functions? And why?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

Input/Output bindings directly interacts with db where we don't have much control. I understand that it eases the development effort but is it fine to do a direct fetch/save to database?

```
public static class CosmosDBFunction
    {
        [Function("CosmosDBFunction")]
        [CosmosDBOutput("%CosmosDb%", "%CosmosCollOut%", ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosConnection", CreateIfNotExists = true)]
        public static object Run(
            [CosmosDBTrigger("%CosmosDb%", "%CosmosCollIn%", ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosConnection",
                LeaseCollectionName = "leases", CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true)] IReadOnlyList<MyDocument> input,
            FunctionContext context)
        {
            var logger = context.GetLogger("CosmosDBFunction");

            if (input != null && input.Any())
            {
                foreach (var doc in input)
                {
                    logger.LogInformation($"Doc Id: {doc.Id}");
                }

                // Cosmos Output
                return input.Select(p => new { id = p.Id });
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Yes that's totally fine. Just make sure you use the `CosmosClient` (if you plan to use that SDK) as a singleton so that its `HttpClient` can be reused and you don't run into socket errors.

Comment: It's really up to you - there's no absolute right or wrong answer. You'll still need input bindings if, say, you're waiting on changefeed, but you can absolutely use the SDK for your own writing (especially if you're doing things like transactional batch writes, writing to multiple collections, etc)

Comment: So one follow up question - Lets say I have integrated this function app api call with a save button click. Whenever user fills the data, I just need to save it to Cosmos. If I don't go with ```CosmosClient``` way and just create new instance of my model which gets saved directly due to output binding mapping
Will each click of user create a new connection with the container?
If yes, Is there any limitation?

Comment: @vinitkumar the ouput binding reuses its `HttpClient` so you won't have to worry about it. The main limitation of the output binding is that it gives you less options, but if it's sufficient for your use case there's no definitive answer on what is better to use.

Answer (score 1):

Input/Output binding are just syntactic sugar on top of the Cosmos SDK that let you do simple queries/reads/write operations. The main benefits:

1. You don't have to write code to maintain the client instance. You can instead use your own client instance, but you need to write code to create it and make sure it follows the Singleton pattern (example https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/AzureFunctions/Startup.cs#L19-L41). All bindings with the same Connection will reuse the same client.
2. They simplify things like auth (if you are using MSI identities instead of Connection Strings, they wire the MSI identity information into the client configuration).

The `CosmosDBTrigger` on the other hand is a more complex piece that it's not just syntactic sugar, it is configuring a [Change Feed Processor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/change-feed-processor?tabs=dotnet) to trigger a Function based on events. This one you probably cannot manually replace with your own client.

Reference for all examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp